# How to start recording `in-progress` outbound calls in Twilio?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php, twilio-programmable-voice

I have Twilio starting, pausing, resuming, and stopping the recording of in-progress inbound calls. However, when I use the same approach, same code, to record in-progress outbound calls I get a `20404` error.

I get that I can record outbound calls from the beginning using the `<record>` verb, but I need to be able to selectively record in-progress outbound calls.

As I say, I have it working for recording in-progress inbound calls, so I'm confused as to why the same approach doesn't work for in-progress outbound calls.

This is my javascript for initiating the recording of a call:

```
document.getElementById('button-record-start').onclick = function () {

    var call_id = $('#call-id').val();
    var csrf_token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

    console.log(call_id);
    console.log(csrf_token);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://my-url.ngrok.io/twilio/recording/start',
        type: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrf_token
        },
        data: {
            call_id: call_id
        },
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (data) { 
            $('#recording-id').val(data.sid);
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log('error:');
            console.log(xhr);
        }
    });
};
```

The ajax calls to this method in my php (Laravel):

```
public $twilio_api_base_url = 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/';

public function start(Request $request)
{
    $call_id = $request->input('call_id');

    $url  =  $this->twilio_api_base_url . env('TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID');
    $url .= '/Calls/' . $call_id . '/Recordings.json';

    $params = [ 'RecordingStatusCallback'=>'https://myapp.com/recording-events', 
                'RecordingStatusCallbackEvent' => 'in-progress'
              ];

    $this->send_request_to_twilio($url, $params);
}
```

Method `send_request_to_twilio` looks like this:

```
public static function send_request_to_twilio($url, $params)
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, env('TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID') . ':' . env('TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN') );

    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);        
}
```

`$url` is formulating correctly. The only thing I can think of is that maybe as I am on a trial account at the moment Twilio changes the `CallSid` when it finishes the obligatory recording telling me that I am on a trial account and then initiates the actual call. Is this correct? If so, how would I find out the new id once this has occurred?

#### Edit:

Adding this to show how I get the call sid:

```
$.getJSON('twilio/token')

    .then(function (data) {

        device = new Twilio.Device(data.token);

        device.on('ready',function (device) {
            console.log('device.on ready')
        });

        device.on('error', function (error) {
            console.log('device.on error');
        });

        device.on('connect', function (conn) {
            console.log('device.on connect');

            var twilio_call_sid = conn.parameters.CallSid;

            log_call_to_database(twilio_call_sid, 'connect');

        });

        // other stuff

  });
```

And this is what my `twilio/token` that the getJSON calls to looks like:

```
public function new_twilio_token()
{
    $twilio_account_sid = env('TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID');
    $twilio_auth_token  = env('TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN');
    $twilio_application_sid = env('TWILIO_APPLICATION_SID');

    $capability = new ClientToken($twilio_account_sid, $twilio_auth_token);
    $capability->allowClientOutgoing($twilio_application_sid);

    $identity = 'tom';
    $capability->allowClientIncoming($identity);
    $token = $capability->generateToken();

    return response()->json(['token' => $token, 'identity' => $identity]);
}
```

Comment: You should get the call SID and it shouldn't change. But how are you getting the call SID from the outbound call?

Comment: Thanks for this. I've made and edit to show how I am getting the call SID from the outbout call. I am just using the code from the javascript quickstart.js. Recording of the outbound calls is now working. I'm not able to tell if this is due to edits in my code or because I upgraded my account to a full account (as listening to those recorded messages was taking far too much time in debugging...)

Comment: Huh, it is likely something you did with your code as having a paid account shouldn't affect this. Glad it's working for you now though.